How to $match to find exact dict in list of dicts
I wonder if there is the way to $match in mongo to find exact dict in list of dicts
I have documents with this fields
{
  _id: ObjectId("6644d9860e3b38f3dd724241"),
  fields: {
    allowed_urls: [
      {
        url: "/my_url/",
        method: "POST"
      },
      {
        url: "/my_url/",
        method: "GET"
      }
    ]
  }
}

And I am filtering my documents like this to find exact document where document has dict with filter params
[{'$match': {'fields.allowed_urls.url': '/my_url/', 'fields.allowed_urls.method': 'POST'}}]

But for some reason if document looks like this
{
  _id: ObjectId("6644d9860e3b38f3dd724241"),
  fields: {
    allowed_urls: [
      {
        url: "/another_url/",
        method: "POST"
      },
      {
        url: "/my_url/",
        method: "GET"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Mongo will find him as well bcs this document has my_url and POST but i want to find document with only exact params in 1 dict. I was trying to do something like fields.allowed_urls.$.method but that does not help

The reason this happens is that each field check can match against any element(s) in the list. So this query
db.collection.find({
  "fields.allowed_urls.url": "/my_url/",
  "fields.allowed_urls.method": "POST"
})

will match a document which has:

"fields.allowed_urls.url": "/my_url/" in any element or sub-document, and
"fields.allowed_urls.method": "POST"  in any element or sub-document.
So the POST matches with the first element in the array and the "/my_url/" matches with the second element in the array.

To make this work against a Single element in the array and an Exact match for the whole element, put the search field under the same parent key/field:
db.collection.find({
  "fields.allowed_urls": {
    "url": "/my_url/",
    "method": "POST"
  }
})

Mongo Playground - Notice how the third document with the extra field other: "only with elemMatch" does not appear in the results even though it has POST and my_url. But, if the field order in the document doesn't match the field order in the query, then it doesn't match. See this example playground with the field order swapped in the query - no matches.
If you wanted to do a Partial match for the object but still within a Single element, like checking 2 out of 3 fields of the same sub-object; or a match with all fields but in any order, use $elemMatch:
db.collection.find({
  "fields.allowed_urls": {
    $elemMatch: {
      "url": "/my_url/",
      "method": "POST"
    }
  }
})

Mongo Playground - This one does return the third document with the extra field.
